# Django rest custom user model creation fails

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a custom user model as following:

```
class Librarian(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    # A library has many librarians
    which_library = models.ForeignKey('Library', related_name='librarians', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have written serializer as following:

```
class LibrarianSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    email = serializers.CharField(source='user.email')
    password = serializers.CharField(source='user.password')

    class Meta:
        model = Librarian
        #fields = '__all__'
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'phone', 'which_library')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.user.email = validated_data.get('user.email', instance.user.email)
        instance.user.password = validated_data.get('user.password', instance.user.password)
        instance.phone = validated_data.get('phone', instance.phone)
        instance.which_library = validated_data.get('which_library', instance.which_library)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print('ok')
        return Librarian.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

It's view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def librarian(request, library_id):
    """
    Create a new librarian for a specific library
    """

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('View')
        serializer = LibrarianSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And I am making a POST request to the corresponding URL with following JSON data:

```
{
    "username": "sample",
    "email": "sample@gmail.com",
    "password": "12345678",
    "phone": "12345",
    "which_library": "1"
}
```

It throws me `Cannot assign "{u'username': u'sample', u'password': u'12345678', u'email': u'sample@gmail.com'}": "Librarian.user" must be a "User" instance` error.

My goal is to create a Librarian (a user must be automatically created), that's why I am sending username, password, email fields as well. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override create method and create User instance first:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')  
    user = User.objects.create(**user_data)
    user.set_password(user_data['password'])
    user.save()  
    return Librarian.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It created the user, however the password was saved as it is and not hashed like otherwise.

Comment: @Nitish oh, yes you need to use `set_password` method.